# How to get all the text before and after some characters using regular expressions

Tags: python, python-re

How can I get some characters from an url, using regular expressions for example:

> https://www.facebook.com/aaaaaa/posts/123456789/sdd

How can I get the characters ***aaaa*** and ***123456789*** that are before and after ***/posts/*** ?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

url = "https://www.facebook.com/aaaaaa/posts/123456789/sdd"

out = re.match('.+/(.+)/posts/(.+)/', url).groups()

print(out)

# Output:

('aaaaaa', '123456789')
```

Comment: Upvoted. Just make sure that you use non-greedy version of `(.+)`, I mean `(.+?)`, otherwise `"https://www.facebook.com/aaaaaa/posts/123456789/sdd/foo/"` won't work as excepted.

Answer (score 0):

```py
url = "https://www.facebook.com/aaaaaa/posts/123456789/sdd"
```

to get `123456789`:

```
url.split('/')[5]
```

for `aaaaaa`

```
url.split('/')[3]
```

Comment: this is not a particularly reliable method of achieving the end result, what if the url has more forward slashes or sth, considering the case I don't think that would happen but still, use of regex would make it more universal

Comment: @Matiiss excatly this was just an example but I'm looking to do this with regex to get a more universal answer

Comment: nothing like is mentioned in the question, but yes we can use regex but need more details to do that, I think